# Category axis lables are overlapping and not showing in Gantt amcharts

Tags: javascript, css, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a pb where my lables are hiding when height is smaller than a value. For example, when

```
#chart {
height: 50vh;
```

}

The result:

[image]

But when the

```
#chart {
    height: 40vh;
}
```

The result:

[image]

As you can see, B and D labels in the category axis are hiddens. but thier values are shown.

How can I change size of others so I can   always see all lables ?. Any suggestion pls ?.

Working code
https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/cse496zg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2sce13n4/

```js
  yAxes: [{
    type: "CategoryAxis",
    dataFields: {
      category: "name"
    },
    renderer: {
      minGridDistance: 1,
      ...
    }
  }],
```

By setting the y-axis [minGridDistance](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/positioning-axis-elements/#Setting_the_density_of_the_the_grid_labels) to a value less than the default of `120`, the grid lines are allowed to be closer together as the chart gets smaller.